# how to show image on form like MessageBoxIcon.Stop image

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

How to show image on form like MessageBoxIcon.Stop image in WindowsFormsApplication in c# 2008

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use one of the icons from the [SystemIcons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons.aspx) class.

The linked MSDN article has an example.

It's not a very good example, as (a) it doesn't Dispose the Bitmap it creates, (b) it doesn't use try/finally to ensure the Graphics object it creates is Disposed in the event of an Exception, and (c) a button click event handler is not the right place to be drawing.

I would handle the `Form`'s Paint event, and draw it as follows:

```
private void MyForm_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawIcon(SystemIcons.Error, 16, 16);
}
```

Comment: +1. Note: as it returns an `Icon`, a `.ToBitmap();` would be required to get an actual `Image`.

Comment: Joe : Thanks Mr. Joe, this is the great help to me and gave me some more knowledge.